# Pytorch DataLoder Is Very Slow

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a problem with the DataLoader form Pytorch, because is very slow.

I did a test to show this, here is the code:

```
data = np.load('slices.npy')
data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 1225))
data = torch.FloatTensor(data).to('cuda')
print(data.shape)
# ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])

class UnlabeledTensorDataset(TensorDataset):
    def __init__(self, data_tensor):
        self.data_tensor = data_tensor
        self.samples = data_tensor.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data_tensor[index]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.samples

test_set = UnlabeledTensorDataset(data)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=data.shape[0])

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in test_loader:
        print(batch.shape)     # ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])
        y_pred = model(batch)
        loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, batch))
        avg_loss = loss
print(round((datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() * 1000, 2))
# ==> 1527.57  (milliseconds)   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with torch.no_grad():
    print(data.shape)     # ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])
    y_pred = model(data)
    loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, data))
    avg_loss = loss
print(round((datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() * 1000, 2))
# ==> 2.0     (milliseconds)    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I will like to use the DataLoader but I want a way to fix the slow issue, dose anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: As a sanity check, did you try to reverse the order and check the timings? i.e., first run without the dataloader, then with it? Just to make sure it isn't some sort of caching.

Answer (score 1):

The time difference seems logical to me:

- On one end you're looping over `test_loader` and doing `1225` inferences.
- On the other, you are doing a single inference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DataLoader is getting the item one by one by applying the `__getitem__(self, index)` function 273468 times (batch size).

My solution is to ditch the DataLoder

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by implementing the **getitems** function

The function takes a list of indices as an argument. In your case, it will return the whole batch in one go which will be dramatically faster.

Also, there is no need to turn this into a torch tensor so early. This should be done by the collate function in the DataLoader. I've implemented the collate_fn as an example. In your particular case, it might also work with the default implementation but as soon as you want to return e.g. inputs and labels, you will need your own one if you are implementing **getitems**

> `

```html
data = np.load('slices.npy')
data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 1225))
print(data.shape)
# ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])

class UnlabeledTensorDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_np_array):
        self.data_np_array = data_np_array
        self.samples = data_np_array.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data_np_array[index]
    
    def __getitems__(self, index_list):
        return self.__getitem__(self, index_list)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.samples

def collate_fn(data):
    return torch.from_numpy(data)


test_set = UnlabeledTensorDataset(data)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=data.shape[0], collate_fn=collate_fn)

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in test_loader:
        batch.to('cuda')
        print(batch.shape)     # ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])
        y_pred = model(batch)
        loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, batch))
        avg_loss = loss
print(round((datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() * 1000, 2))
# ==> 1527.57  (milliseconds)   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

start = datetime.datetime.now()
with torch.no_grad():
    print(data.shape)     # ==> torch.Size([273468, 1225])
    y_pred = model(data)
    loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred, data))
    avg_loss = loss
print(round((datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() * 1000, 2))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you had inputs and labels in separate numpy array and returned them as a tuple, you would be doing something like this:

```html
def collate_fn(data):
    inputs, labels = data
    return torch.from_numpy(inputs), torch.from_numpy(labels)
```